# ruby on rails regular expression find and remove tags between tags in html string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

I'm working in ruby on rails and need the following:

remove all "br" html tags between "code" html tags in a string of html. The "code" tags might occur more than once.

Now, it's not screen scraping I'm trying to do. I have a blog and would like to allow people to use the code html tags only in the comments. So when formatting the string I normally use simple_format but I'd like it to ignore code html tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html

Comment: thanks Chris, was fun reading it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely positively *have* to use regexp, try this one, which catches all `<br>`, `<br/>` and `<br />` tags:

```
str.gsub(/<code>.+?<\/code>/) {|s| s.gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/, "")}
```

Tested with:

```
str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br />, <code>consectetur adipisicing elit<br />, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore<br> et dolore magna aliqua</code>. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi<br/> ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <code>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit<br /> in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore<br/> eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</code> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,<br /> sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
p str.gsub(/<code>.+?<\/code>/) {|s| s.gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/, "")}
```

If you don't have to use regexp, use an html parser like nokogiri.

Comment: thank you. I already found another simple_format hack that did it for me. The problem was the logic as i could not figure out a method of using regexp in a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Using Hpricot or a HTML parser of your choice would be a far, far better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I second on Hpricot, but what are trying to do? Attempting to do some sort of web-scraping or are you parsing the HTML from a model?

Comment: i'm trying to edit the simple_format helper to ignore code tags and everything in between